# Building Liblinphone for iOS

Tags: voip, linphone-sdk

I am planning to develop an iOS application where I need to use VOIP services. I found Liblinphone which is one such open source API for VOIP.

My requirements:

1. Making voice call & receiving
2. Making video calls & receiving
3. Making voice call conferences.

Are these all possible with Liblinphone? Are there any other opensource VOIP libraries for achieving this better than Liblinphone?

Any help and tutorial links are a big helpfor me.

Comment: [Zoiper](http://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-sdk) is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at siphon (http://code.google.com/p/siphon/).

From their homepage:

Home of the World's first free SIP/VoIP application for iPhone and iPod Touch 1 and 2.

Siphon SIP/VoIP project is the first in his category that works on iPhone and iPod Touch 2 with headset for all SIP providers. It is a native application approved running on 2.X using internal micro/speaker and headset.

The Application supports the SIP standard, preserving compatibility with hundreds of SIP providers and offers a GUI which preserves the apple design of native iPhone applications.

Comment: The documentation is poorly written to be honest, where do I start from using this project?